# Can not route to child in angular 7

Tags: angular, routes

I have a lazy loaded module `ManagerDashboard` that has some children routes:

**app-routing.module**

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'manager-dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/manager-dashboard/manager-dashboard.module#ManagerDashboardPageModule' },
];
```

**manager-dashboard-routing.module**

```
const managerRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ManagerDashboardPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'consultations',
        component: ConsultationsPage,
      },
      {
        path: 'weigh-ins',
        component: VisitsPage,
        children: [
          {
            path: ":id",
            component: VisitPage
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'finance',
        component: ConsultationsPage
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'consultations',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

And in my `VisitsPage` I have links that should link out to the `VisitPage` but for some reason my view does not change after the URL changes (also there are no errors).

**VisitsPage**

```
this.router.navigate(['manager-dashboard', 'weigh-ins', client.check_in_id])
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code

```
{
  path: 'weigh-ins',
  component: VisitsPage,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":id",
      component: VisitPage
    }
  ]
}
```

Make it

```
{
  path: 'weigh-ins/:id'
  component: VisitsPage,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it would be great if you check [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if you hadn't already. I also suggest that you explain why you had to do these changes :)